# Intuition for defining basis for Hamiltonian in momentum representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, quantum-computer, ising-model

I am going through [Quantum information approach to the Ising model: Entanglement in chains of qubits](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0312154.pdf) by Stelmachovic et al. In Section A.4, the authors determines the eigenvalues and eigenstates of the Hamiltonian of a spin chain on a ring expressed using the momentum representation. The Hamiltonian is as follows.

$$
H = \sum_q \left[-\lambda \cos q \left(\eta^\dagger_q \eta^\dagger_{2 \pi -q}+ 2 \eta^\dagger_q \eta_q - \eta_q \eta_{2 \pi -q}\right) - \lambda i \sin q \left(\eta^\dagger_q \eta^\dagger_{2 \pi - q} + \eta_q \eta_{2 \pi -q}\right) + 2 \left(\eta^\dagger_q \eta_q - \frac{1}{2}\right) \right]
$$

For a specific value of $q$ when $q \ne 0, \pi$:

$$
H_q = -\lambda \cos q \left(2 \eta^\dagger_q \eta_q + 2 \eta^\dagger_{2 \pi -q} \eta_{2 \pi -q}\right) -\lambda i \sin q \left(2 \eta^\dagger_q \eta^\dagger_{q} + 2 \eta^\dagger_{2 \pi -q} \eta_{2 \pi -q}\right) + 2 \left(\eta^\dagger_q \eta_q + \eta^\dagger_{2\pi -q} \eta_{2\pi -q} - 1\right)
$$

Now, for $H_q$, the authors define the following basis.

$$
|\phi_1\rangle = \eta^\dagger_q |0\rangle\\
|\phi_2\rangle = \eta^\dagger_{2 \pi - q} |0\rangle\\
|\phi_3\rangle = |0\rangle\\
|\phi_4\rangle = \eta^\dagger_{2\pi - q} \eta^\dagger_q |0\rangle
$$

**My question:**
What are the intuitions behind these choices?

**My effort:**
I understand that $|\phi_3\rangle = |0\rangle$ is arbitrary. Then $\eta^\dagger_q$ and $\eta^\dagger_{2 \pi - q}$ take $|\phi_3\rangle$ to $|\phi_1\rangle$ and $|\phi_2\rangle$ respectively. Finally, we consider a basis $|\phi_4\rangle$ which is the eigenvector of the combination of $\eta^\dagger_q$ and $\eta^\dagger_{2 \pi - q}$. I understand up to this.

We didn't consider the operators $\eta^\dagger_q \eta_q$, $\eta^\dagger_{2 \pi -q} \eta_{2 \pi -q}$ because $\eta^\dagger_q \eta_q |\phi_3\rangle = \eta^\dagger_{2 \pi -q} \eta_{2 \pi -q} |\phi_3\rangle = 0$. The only operator left in $H_q$ is $\eta^\dagger_q \eta^\dagger_{q}$.

**I would like to know why $\eta^\dagger_q \eta^\dagger_{q}$ was not considered while defining $|\phi_4\rangle$'s.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $\eta^{q}$ are Fermionic operators, therefore $\eta^{2}_{q}=0=\eta^{\dagger 2}_{q}$.

Comment: thanks. What happens when there are multiple modes for creation operators?   $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q} = ?$$\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}\eta^{\dagger}_{q} = ?$

Comment: In that case $\eta_{q}^{\dagger}\eta_{-q}^{\dagger}=-\eta_{-q}^{\dagger}\eta_{q}^{\dagger}$. As the are anti-commutating.

Comment: I meant $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |0\rangle = ?$ Sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: In that case $|0\rangle$ will be mapped to the first excited state.

Comment: I am trying to understand that. $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |0\rangle = \eta^{\dagger}_{q}  |1\rangle$. So, are you suggesting that $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}  |1\rangle = |1\rangle$?

Comment: $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |0\rangle =   |q,-q\rangle$.

Comment: $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}$ is working on one qubit  $|0\rangle$. But   $|q,-q\rangle$ is a two qubit state. I am not getting where this second qubit come from.

Comment: $|0\rangle$ is the ground state. It is not necessary to be single qubit state.

Comment: Moreover, how is $ |q,-q\rangle = |1\rangle$?

Comment: May I also ask this ? $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |1\rangle =   ?$ Is $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |1\rangle =   0?$

Comment: No, i guess. Say $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |1\rangle =   |a,-a\rangle$. Hitting by $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}$ or $\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}$ from left gives zero, as annihilation (creation) operators are anti-commutating.

Comment: If $\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |1\rangle =   0$, as you have said, shouldn't $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |1\rangle =   \eta^{\dagger}_{q} \cdot 0 = 0$? Moreover, I understand that $|q, -q\rangle$ is the first excited state. But, what is $|a, -a\rangle$?

Comment: I mean $|a,-a\rangle$ is the same as $|q,-q\rangle$.

Comment: Isn't $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |1\rangle =   \eta^{\dagger}_{q} \cdot 0 = 0$?

Comment: No. Its zero because $\eta^{2}=0$.

Comment: Are you suggesting that  $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q} = (\eta^{\dagger}_{q})^2 = (\eta^{\dagger}_{-q})^2$?

Comment: I think I understand what is going on. $\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  |1\rangle = \eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}   \eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}   |0\rangle = (\eta^{\dagger}_{q}\eta^{\dagger}_{-q}  )^2 |0\rangle = 0$.